# Inconsistency between CloudWatch alert and Container Insights

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

I am running a .NET 6 container in ECS Fargate. My task definition defines the task size:

```
Task Memory: 1024
Task CPU: 512
```

The task has 2 containers running - the service and the envoy proxy. The containers define the following:

```
.NET Service
CPU Units: 0
Hard/Soft memory limits: --/--

Envoy
CPU Units: 0
Hard/Soft memory limits: 500/--
```

The the ECS Portal, the service shows the CPUUtilization metric in the following graph:
[image]

This graph seems to indicate that CPU utilization is quite low.

I have a CloudWatch alarm configured for when the Average CpuUtilized of the service goes over 90%, however it seems to alarm despite the other metrics indicating very low utilization.

[image]

Container Insights also shows low utilization.

[image]

I suspect it could be due to not specifying the `CPU Units` for the task containers. How can I ensure the metric used for the CloudWatch is consistent with other insights and metrics?

**Edit**

Even when specifying the `CPU Units` for each container in the task, I have the same inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

The `ECS/ContainerInsights` `CpuUtilized` metric must be used in conjunction with the `CpuReserved` metric when creating an alarm.

[image]

Alternatively, the alarm can be created using the `AWS/ECS` `CpuUtilization` metric.